# Disabling VBA alerts

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to disable the message box: "There's already data here. Do you want to replace it?"

I've tried to disable VBA alerts, but without success.

First, I went to Excel Settings> Advanced > Alert before overwriting cells, but it didn't work.

I've also tried to place the statement in my code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

But, I'm getting multiple errors depending where I place the statement.

Since I already have an application as part of my code, I tried also to change the application name to the same name as the variable is set in my code, but I'm getting: " The enumerator of the collection cannot find en element with the specified index.

```
SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Since this is a huge code I will post only the beginning of it. Please see below:

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim SapGui
Dim Application
Dim Connection
Dim Session
Dim WSHShell


If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(Session) Then
   Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If

SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: You should probably not name your variable `Application`. That is the name used for the Excel application object. It could get very confusing to have two important objects using the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below line at the beginning of your code:

```
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
```

Then you can do the opposite at the end of your code to revert this setting.